# Trouble connecting with NXOS modules in Ansible: list index out of range

Tags: ansible, network-programming

I cannot get a simple playbook to work against a Cisco Nexus switch using Ansible 2.9.13. I get a vague index out of range error.

Here is my inventory file:

```
[nxos:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_password=password
ansible_network_os=nxos
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=enable
ansible_become_password=password

[nxos]
nxos-sw01 ansible_host=172.23.180.12
```

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- name: "nxos configure nxapi"
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "enble api"
    nxos_nxapi:
      enable_https: yes
```

When I execute I get an error about "list index out of range" that does not yield any helpful output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i test.inv test.yml -vvvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.0
  config file = /home/some.guy/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/some.guy/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/some.guy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /home/some.guy/.ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /home/some.guy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.pyc

PLAYBOOK: test.yml **************************************************************************************************************************************************
Positional arguments: test.yml
become_method: sudo
inventory: (u'/home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv',)
forks: 5
tags: (u'all',)
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
1 plays in test.yml

PLAY [nxos configure banner] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [enble api] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.yml:6
<172.23.180.12> attempting to start connection
<172.23.180.12> using connection plugin network_cli
fatal: [nxos-sw01]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/bin/ansible-connection\", line 342, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/usr/bin/ansible-connection\", line 261, in main\n    task_uuid = sys.argv[2]\nIndexError: list index out of range\n"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
nxos-sw01                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I have tried different NXOS modules and using the NXAPI connectivity method. I can't seem to get anything to work. I can connect manually (SSH) to the switch from this server.

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is attempt to run just ansible against the device. Something wrong with how connection info is being parsed ? By running the below I am bypassing my playbook entirely and still get same error.

```
$ ansible -vvvv nxos-sw01 -m ping -i test.inv
ansible 2.9.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/etc/ansible/modules', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/napalm_ansible']
  ansible python module location = /home/some.guy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/some.guy/tmp/ansible/test.inv inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /home/some.guy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.pyc
META: ran handlers
<172.23.180.12> attempting to start connection
<172.23.180.12> using connection plugin network_cli
nxos-sw01 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/bin/ansible-connection\", line 342, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/usr/bin/ansible-connection\", line 261, in main\n    task_uuid = sys.argv[2]\nIndexError: list index out of range\n"
```

EDIT2: I ended up opening a bug ticket on Github about this issue:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/72214

Comment: not able to find `enable_https` in the module documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/nxos_config_module.html

Comment: slight typo on that play attempt, corrected. i tried other modules like the one for the banner. The issue appears to be how connection info is being parsed. Its trying to reference the 2nd element of "sys.argv[2]" but it doesn't exist?

Comment: see 2nd example https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/nxos_nxapi_module.html   change false to true

Comment: If I got even simpler and try to set state: absent or state: present I get the exact same error. It really seems like an issue parsing the connection info for how Ansible should even *attempt* to connect to the switch. Doesn't even seem to get to part of running the module to do work.

Comment: It is polite to advise the SO community that you [already opened a GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/72214) in order to keep those interested in helping you from wasting their time searching issues on your behalf

Answer (score 0):

After getting help on #ansible-network I was able to figure this out. Apparently I installed additional copies of python2/3 under my home directory and that was being preferred, as shown in the debug output in my OP:

```
ansible python module location = /home/some.guy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
```

After removing that .local path from my home directory I now see ansible --version reporting 2.9.13 and the NXOS module works correctly.